# How to make angularjs table directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The table's content is loaded by ajax and I want to show loading content like this. How can I turn these two `ng-show` into directive

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>bbb</th>
        <th>ccc</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="isLoading">Loading...</tr>
    <tr ng-show="!isLoading" ng-repeat="log in logs">
        <td>{{log.aaa}}</td>
        <td>{{log.bbb}}</td>
        <td>{{log.ccc}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly would you want directive to do?  Seems like over complicating something that is already really simple, easy to read and is core functionality. Also note that `<table>` is very limited on allowed types of child elements so you can't use a custom tag as a child of `<table>`

Comment: Actually I'd like to make a directive like `<table><tr>...</tr><tr loading ng-repeat="xxx"></tr></table>`

Comment: Well that is quite different from question asking only how to turn `ng-show`'s into directive. Would likely help for you to read [ask]. being as detailed and specific as possible avoids confusion and guessing on our part. Asking a good question does take a bit of effort but will also get much quicker response

Answer (score 1):

`tableDirective`:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('tableDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        isLoading: '=',
        logs: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'table.html'
    }
});
```

`table.html`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>bbb</th>
        <th>ccc</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="isLoading">Loading...</tr>
    <tr ng-show="!isLoading" ng-repeat="log in logs">
        <td>{{log.aaa}}</td>
        <td>{{log.bbb}}</td>
        <td>{{log.ccc}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`view`:

```
<table-directive is-loading="isLoading" logs="logs"></table-directive>
```

`isLoading` and `logs` from your controller.